# Тлетворный - what does it mean?

Tags: значения, idioms

What does the word Тлетворный mean in this sentence? Is it an idiom?

> Одно время Тлетворный игрался в тибетскую карту.

Comment: As google shows only one definite place where that sentence comes from, I must say that the author used there the word "Тлетворный" with no other means but similar to "Evildoer" and such.

Comment: are you aware of translate.google.com ?

Comment: It is a nickname, because it is written with a capital letter.  The meaning of the word is provided in the answers below.

Answer (score 3):

In this sentence it looks like surname.
In general - "Тлетворный" - similar to "putrescent"

Comment: it is not similar to "putrescent", no way. At first, "putrescent" means `undergoing the process of decay; rotting`, while `тлетворный` means something **inducing** rotting, perversion etc, mostly in a figurative meaning

Comment: it derives from two words "тлеть" (to rot) and "творить" (to create), so the word "putrescent" is definitely not the one to use

Comment: Sorry for it, can't get english word for it, had to use dictionaries to find something similar. Thanks for explanation :)

Comment: @Llorephie Simply "_harmful_" should be OK, unless "_тлетворный_" is used in a truly high-stylish poetical context.

Comment: @Llorephie: I think "putrefactive" is the word you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

ТЛЕТВОРНЫЙ, -ая, -ое; -рен, -рна, -рно. Книжн. 1. Порождающий тление или порождённый тлением. Т. запах, воздух. Т. яд. 2. Оказывающий пагубное, разлагающее воздействие на кого-, что-л.; вредоносный. Т-ая атмосфера. Т-ая пропаганда. Оказывать т-ое влияние на кого-л. <Тлетворность, -и; ж. Т. духа. Т. воздействия.

Depending on meaning this word has the following translations.

> - **pestilential** **|ˌpestɪˈlenʃəl|**  — чумной, пагубный, тлетворный, вредный, отвратительный
>
> - **pestilent |ˈpestɪlənt|**  — ядовитый, тлетворный, смертоносный, вредный, надоедливый, назойливый
>
> - **harmful |ˈhɑːrmfəl|**  — вредный, пагубный, губительный, тлетворный, разлагающий
>   Смотрите также
>
> тлетворный дух коррупции — the stench of corruption
>   Родственные слова, либо редко употребляемые в данном значении
>
> -  **putrid |ˈpjuːtrəd|**  — гнилой, вонючий, испорченный, мерзкий
>
> - **noxious |ˈnɑːkʃəs|**  — вредный, ядовитый, пагубный
>
> - **pernicious |pərˈnɪʃəs|**  — пагубный, вредный, гибельный